# SQL Frequency report with null values in columns

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, multiple-columns, frequency

I need help creating a frequency report for data that crosses multiple columns of data. Here's an example of my data:

[Sample Data Example]

[image: 1]

And here's how I need for the data to read, except that I can't figure out how to get the frequency.

[Frequency Report]

[image: 2]

There may be null values in a column in a particular row, but I still need that distinct row counted. I have all of the code working except how to get the frequency/count.

This is what I've tried, but all I get are 0s for the frequency.

```
select distinct TEST, PANEL, UNITS, LOINC, count(distinct TEST, PANEL, UNITS, LOINC) as FREQ
from DEV_HEALTHTERM.SOURCE.LAB  
GROUP BY TEST, PANEL, UNITS, LOINC
ORDER BY FREQ DESC;
```

Can someone please help?
Thank you.
Robin

Answer (score 0):

you should count columns that are not participating in the group by .in your case you can just use * :

```
select TEST, PANEL, UNITS, LOINC, count(*) as FREQ
from DEV_HEALTHTERM.SOURCE.LAB  
GROUP BY TEST, PANEL, UNITS, LOINC
ORDER BY FREQ DESC;
```

also you don't need distinct , since you are groping by , It's redundant.